# How to pass USB port through to qemu with chroot

Tags: qemu

I created a chroot environment with qemu to get a x86 linux kernel to run on a Raspberry Pi 3. Do you know how to pass the USB port through when running `sudo chroot /home/pi/chroot-stretch-i386/ /bin/su -l root`? Is there a config file for that?

Thanks for your help.

See: https://www.novaspirit.com/2019/04/15/run-x86-arm/

Comment: The `sudo chroot...` command you've given doesn't have anything to do with Qemu. It would be the `qemu` command that would allow you to define a pass-through.

Comment: The instructions OP is following don't actually explicitly run `qemu` at any point. Instead, they rely on `binfmt-support` and `qemu-user-static` to automatically run foreign-architecture (x86) binaries through `qemu`. So it would seem to be necessary to investigate configuration files in `/usr/share/binfmts` to find the wrapper script that will run `qemu` for x86 binaries, and then find a suitable place to modify the actual `qemu` invocation to enable USB passthrough. I don't have such a set-up at the moment so I cannot check the details, can someone else continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

I did this (the other way around, running the Raspberry system on x86, but it might help):

```
# mount /dev/sdxy /mnt/pi # the pi's sdcard
```

You should now copy qemu-arm-static to /mnt/pi/usr/bin, but you've alredy set that up.

```
# cd /mnt/pi
# mount -t proc proc proc/
# mount -t sysfs sys sys/
# mount -o bind /dev dev/
# export QEMU_DEVICE=qemu-xhci
# chroot /mnt/pi
```

That's it, now I can run *lsusb* and do things like

```
cat /dev/input/mouse0
```

inside the chroot and see the input.

Does this help? What are you trying to access over USB?